# How can I make a Input with a span with :before pseudo class?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

It's my firts question in StackOverflow ...
I have a input type button, and I want to add a pseudo:class before for this animation (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emodKG). I know it's impossible because input can't contain something. So I try to add a span with my input, this span I give the class "btn" from CodePen ...

The problem is that the span is over my input, I have the animation but it's not clickable.

```
<span class="btn"><input type="button"></span>
```

Comment: Use a `<button>` instead? They do in the Codepen you linked.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I can't, I have to use this input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, I think this will help you :)

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-width: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  transition: background-color .8s;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
.btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(236, 240, 241, .2);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.btn:active:before {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  transition: width .1s ease-out, padding-top .1s ease-out;
}
.btn input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="btn"><input type="button" />Button</label>
```

Comment: Thank, It's what i want to do